# Loading and Refreshing DataGrid in WinForms using C# .Net Framework

Tags: c#

I am looking for some review on the code I am about to provide below.

I'd like to improve my coding in general and happy to hear any comments from the community.

The goal of this code is simply load `dataGridView1` with some data from MySQL and Refresh it with a click of a button.

I have not yet tried using automatic refresh. But will look into it soon or later.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Final_Version
{
    public partial class Form19 : Form
    {
        public Form19()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form19_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshGridHistory();
        }




        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Final_Version.Properties.Settings.technicalConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        public void RefreshGridHistory()
        {
            // MySQL connection string
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
            {
                //Seelct query
                using (var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select r.date_requested, u.username, r.product_code, r.customer_code " +
                                                                   " from verify v join request r on v.request_id = r.id join users u on r.user_id = u.id join" +
                                                                    " users u2 on v.user_id = u2.id where v.status = 'Verified' or v.status = 'Rejected';", conn))
                {
                    using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
                    {
                        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);

                        //Assign headers to Data Grid View
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
                        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Date Requested";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "User Requested";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Product Code";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Customer Code";

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshGridHistory();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A couple remarks

- You don't need a dataset here, just a datatable. Datasets come into play when you have multiple tables with relationships.
- I would rather set the headers and the overall layout for the `datagridview` **early**, for example right after `InitializeComponent()`
- But in fact I would not even do this in code. I would simply customize the control in the form layout window, and set all properties that can defined before runtime.
- Good **naming conventions** are important - `Form19` is not a good, descriptive name. Nor is `dataGridView1` or `button1`. These are default names.
- This code may not be complete, but this form has several imports that are unneeded: Drawing, Threading,... don't add more than what is strictly needed, that only clutters the code for nothing. Yes, using LINQ would be a good idea, if not here it will be useful at other places.
- The **scope** of some variables can be moved up to form level, for example `DS`, because in another procedure you might want to check the number of rows retrieved

---

I don't understand why you have:

```
using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
{
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);

    //Assign headers to Data Grid View
    ...
}
```

What you effectively use is variable `DS`, not `dataSet` (by the way `dataSet` is a terrible name for a dataset...be careful with **reserved keywords**)

---

The string concatenation for the SQL is ugly. LINQ is an option. Another option for multi-line string literals is a [verbatim string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) using the `@` symbol so you can define a variable for your SQL like this:

```
string sql = @"SELECT r.date_requested, u.username, r.product_code, r.customer_code 
FROM verify v JOIN request r ON v.request_id = r.id JOIN users u ON r.user_id = u.id JOIN 
users u2 on v.user_id = u2.id
WHERE v.status = 'Verified' OR v.status = 'Rejected';";
```

Even in this day and age of large monitors, I think it is reasonable to limit column width to around 80 - your code extends to column 163. It is not convenient for the human eye to scan/scroll long lines of text.

---

Final point: comments. You have some comments in your code but they are not helpful:

```
// MySQL connection string
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))

//Seelct query
using (var mySqlDataAdapter...
```

It is quite obvious what these lines do, I have not learned or remembered anything noteworthy from your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the review! I will get this on board!

Comment: Hi, is LINQ only for SQL Server? Because I am using MySQL

Comment: No, in fact LINQ can even be used without a database, an iterator of some sort will do, could be a collection or another data structure [Language Integrated Query (LINQ)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

Answer (score 2):

**Single responsibility**

Move the query logic to different class, let's call it DAL for example. In this implementation you are returning DataTable.  Returning a list of some class instead will make sure changes in the DB query/ schema will not affect the GUI but only the DAL class.

**LINQ**

You can write the sql query using linq and then if you have syntax errors they will be cache during completion

**Grid**

I wonder why  you set the columns headers multiple times?

Think about this scenario: when the form loads, If the query return 0 results or there is a connection problem, how the grid will look like?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the review! I will look into LINQ and also regarding the Grid - what do you mean I set the columns multiple times? I set it once?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the columns headers